# Control not updating when binding data source changes?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Sorry if this has been asked but I can't find it.
I'm trying to bind a textbox to a datasource, but the textbox isn't updating when the datasource changes... Here's my code, can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

```
public Controller()
{
            myForm.databaseTextBinding = new Binding("Text", ac, "connString");
        myForm.databaseTextBinding.ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;

        myForm.setupSources();
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Binding databaseTextBinding;


    public void setupSources()
    {
        DatabaseTextBox.DataBindings.Add(databaseTextBinding);

    }
}
```

UPDATE:
I can now make textboxes that will update. I have a new problem though. The datasource itself changes by me making a new ac object. But if I do that, the binding now longer updates. I've considered that maybe the property isn't changing but I'm sure that it is!

Eg this works

```
ac.cString = "ABC";
ac.cString = "DEF";
```

but this doesn't...

```
ac = new AccessConnector(path);
ac.cString = "ABC"; 
ac.cString = "DEF";
```

Answer (score 4):

Does the type of the bound object (i.e. ac) implement INotifyPropertyChanged? if so, does the property "connString" raise a PropertyChanged event when it's changed?

if not, you may have a look at the [INotifyPropertyChanged sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

EDIT:

the part does not work is due to you did not change your binding to the new object - it's still bound to the old object. when you assign a new object to the reference variable ac, the binding to the original object won't change - thus it still points to the previous object.

Comment: Despite the age of this answer, it's still easy to get burned by this if you dutifully add your `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;` and `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MyProperty)));` but *forget* to add ` : INotifyPropertyChanged` to your class definition. Don't ask me how I know this :)

Answer (score 2):

Presuming that your `Binding` is binding a `BindingSource` to the textbox, you need to add a `BindingSource.ResetBindings()` to your code.

Comment: No I'm not using a binding source, should I be?

Comment: Not necessarily, but they do help in winforms programming.